# HIVE HA via zookeeper (JDBC)

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive

I appreciate every help, thank you!
I'm using Hive HA via zookeeper, this is my hive-site.xml (HA part):

```
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.support.dynamic.service.discovery</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.zookeeper.namespace</name>
  <value>hiveserver2</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>hadoopcluster01:2181,hadoopcluster02:2181</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.zookeeper.client.port</name>
  <value>2181</value>
</property>
```

When I'm using beeline:

```
 !connect jdbc:hive2://hadoopcluster01:2181,hadoopcluster02:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2
```

It's perfectly works!

When I'm using cloudera jdbc (v: 2.5.15) connect to a single hiveserver2:

```
Class.forName("com.cloudera.hive.jdbc41.HS2Driver");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://hadoopcluster01:10000", prop);
```

It's perfectly works!

But when I try to connect to zookeeper via jdbc:

```
Class.forName("com.cloudera.hive.jdbc41.HS2Driver");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://zk=hadoopcluster01:2181,hadoopcluster02:2181/hiveserver2", prop);
```

not work:

```
[2015-11-11 09:35:29.426] boot - 5832  INFO [main] --- ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=hadoopcluster01:2181 sessionTimeout=3000 watcher=com.cloudera.hive.hivecommon.api.ZookeeperDynamicDiscovery$1@74455848
[2015-11-11 09:35:29.426] boot - 5832  INFO [main-SendThread(hadoopcluster01.nebu.local:2181)] --- ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server hadoopcluster01.nebu.local/192.168.99.71:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[2015-11-11 09:35:29.426] boot - 5832  INFO [main] --- ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=hadoopcluster02:2181 sessionTimeout=3000 watcher=com.cloudera.hive.hivecommon.api.ZookeeperDynamicDiscovery$1@4e7912d8
[2015-11-11 09:35:29.426] boot - 5832  INFO [main-SendThread(hadoopcluster01.nebu.local:2181)] --- ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to hadoopcluster01.nebu.local/192.168.99.71:2181, initiating session
[2015-11-11 09:35:29.426] boot - 5832  INFO [main-SendThread(hadoopcluster02.nebu.local:2181)] --- ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server hadoopcluster02.nebu.local/192.168.99.72:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
[2015-11-11 09:35:29.426] boot - 5832  INFO [main-SendThread(hadoopcluster02.nebu.local:2181)] --- ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to hadoopcluster02.nebu.local/192.168.99.72:2181, initiating session
[2015-11-11 09:35:29.426] boot - 5832  INFO [main-SendThread(hadoopcluster01.nebu.local:2181)] --- ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server hadoopcluster01.nebu.local/192.168.99.71:2181, sessionid = 0x150f58353570006, negotiated timeout = 6000
[2015-11-11 09:35:29.457] boot - 5832  INFO [main-SendThread(hadoopcluster02.nebu.local:2181)] --- ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server hadoopcluster02.nebu.local/192.168.99.72:2181, sessionid = 0x250f582c7990001, negotiated timeout = 6000
[2015-11-11 09:35:29.457] boot - 5832  INFO [main] --- ZooKeeper: Session: 0x250f582c7990001 closed
[2015-11-11 09:35:29.457] boot - 5832  INFO [main-EventThread] --- ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
java.sql.SQLException: [Cloudera][HiveJDBCDriver](500170) Error occured while setting up Zookeeper Dynamic Discovery: [Cloudera][HiveJDBCDriver]Error Occured Connecting to ZooKeeper: At: hadoopcluster01:2181 With Error Message: Path length must be > 0..
    at com.cloudera.hive.hivecommon.api.ZooKeeperEnabledExtendedHS2Factory.createClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hivecommon.core.HiveJDBCCommonConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.hive.core.HiveJDBCConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudera.hive.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at com.nebu.nldpconnection.main.NLDPConnectionTest.getConnection(NLDPConnectionTest.java:81)
    at com.nebu.nldpconnection.main.NLDPConnectionTest.run(NLDPConnectionTest.java:214)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:677)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:695)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
Caused by: com.cloudera.hive.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Cloudera][HiveJDBCDriver](500170) Error occured while setting up Zookeeper Dynamic Discovery: [Cloudera][HiveJDBCDriver]Error Occured Connecting to ZooKeeper: At: hadoopcluster01:2181 With Error Message: Path length must be > 0..
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: It's complaining about the path length being 0 in `hadoopcluster01:2181`. Have you tried adding a `/`: `hadoopcluster01:2181/`? Some Hadoop tools can be silly about these kinds of things.

Comment: Yes I tried, I tried also with a single zookeeper too:
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://zk=hadoopcluster01:2181/hiveserver2", prop);
But thank you for your advice!

Comment: Can we connect to zookeeper using the pyhon and the connect to hiveserver2 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try and use it after this modification.
I succeeded like this.

[You]

> jdbc:hive2://zk=hadoopcluster01:2181,hadoopcluster02:2181/hiveserver2

[My Proposal]

> jdbc:hive2://zk=hadoopcluster01:2181/hiveserver2,hadoopcluster02:2181/hiveserver2